# How to get complex bounds of an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bounds

Some elements has complex bounds, for example `a` link with `line-height` css property > 1.0, or `svg` objects. It is important to determine (x,y) area in which I can click to trigger click event. Using javascript's `.click()` method on element is not a solution for my case.

I found only `getBoundingClientRect`, but it is too rough. Click in the middle of area, is a miss click at example below. You also can read this article to see examples of complex bounds. https://travishorn.com/buttons-with-custom-shapes-cabdcde7dfd1

```html
<div style="width: 100px">
    <a href="#" style="line-height: 1.4; border: red 1px solid;">long link long link long link</a>
</div>
```

I want to have function, that returns list of closed curves that describes element bounds.

Comment: _I want to have function, that returns list of closed curves that describes element bounds._ What have you tried so far?

Comment: @skyline3000 I found only `getBoundingClientRect`, but it is too rough.

Comment: You should look at the SVG API reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model#SVG_interfaces but I don't believe there are any native APIs to get complex bounds of SVG elements. You'll have to write something yourself analyzing the properties of the SVG elements and compute the geometry, or search around the web for someone who has already come up with a solution.